# read messages on a streaming socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, streaming

I'm writing a client server model application, The server sends a lot of messages (with different sizes) on very high rates on a stream connection to the client, The client reads these messages on a buffer larger than the expected message size

```
while (ret = read (sd, buf, sizeof buf) > 0)
{
      // decode message here
}
```

The problem here is that the client may read more than one message on the buffer like that, If I supposed the buffer is B and the messages are M#, It will receive the message as following

|----B----|----B----|----B----|----B----| ....

|-M1--|-M2-|--M3-|-M4-|---M5---|--M6-| ....

which makes the decoding of the message incorrect. So, I want to receive the messages as following (only one message per buffer)

|----B----|----B----|----B----|----B----| ....

|-M1--|,,|-M2-|,,,|--M3-|,,|-M4-| .... (,,, are nothing, just for formatting)

Noting that, I have to use streaming connection and I don't like not use any delimiter between messages

Comment: Only send one message in your server?

Comment: If not a delimiter, use a header with a message size field...

Comment: use the constant message size.., equal to buffer size

Comment: @AdeelAhmed: The message sizes are variable

Comment: @patriiice: I think this a good idea although it needs a heavy change in the decoding function

Comment: You can pad your message by zeroes to make it equal to size of B...

Comment: @AdeelAhmed: good idea, I've already thought about it but I was wondering about if it will make overhead on the network traffic in case of thousands (or even millions) of messages!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot control how the bytes of the stream are delivered to the application, it's a *stream of bytes*, not of individual messages.

Even if you don't "like" delimiters, this is exactly why they are being used so often. It's not a fun idea, it's a basic solution to this problem. Not "liking" it isn't very interesting as objections go.

Your only hope, excepting delimiters, is to implement message parsing that can properly determine at all times if it has a full message or not, and if so which message. If the messages are "prefixing"; so that a particular sequence of bytes B can be both a full message M1 and the start of M2, then I think you're toast.

Comment: I thought there are other techniques to solve this problem rather than delimiters, but I may use delimiters as a final solution. however I think the message parsing is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of delimiters. Whatever character is "illegal" in your protocol will make an excellent delimiter, but if you can choose a printable character that will make the protocol more readable in a sniffer or when using telnet.

Basing your protocol on XML or similar structured data is also an option. This makes a more complex delimiter.

Binary protocols often use TLVs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) where the length specifies the number of bytes in the message (only the value part or both type, length and value).